# "failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected" when using MPI

Tags: tensorflow, mpi4py

I'm trying to use mpi4py with tensorflow.
The test code is shown below

```py
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type='GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(devices=gpus[0], device_type='GPU')
```

When I run

```
python3 test2.py
```

It gives me good result

```
2022-04-18 21:41:38.760540: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2022-04-18 21:41:40.404001: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2022-04-18 21:41:40.480838: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:81:00.0 name: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB computeCapability: 8.0
coreClock: 1.41GHz coreCount: 108 deviceMemorySize: 39.59GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 1.41TiB/s
2022-04-18 21:41:40.480883: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2022-04-18 21:41:40.492554: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2022-04-18 21:41:40.492590: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2022-04-18 21:41:40.496439: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2022-04-18 21:41:40.498045: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2022-04-18 21:41:40.499642: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.11
2022-04-18 21:41:40.502452: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2022-04-18 21:41:40.503149: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2022-04-18 21:41:40.505705: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
```

But if I use MPi and run

```
mpirun -np 2 python3 test2.py
```

It cannot find the gpu then.

````
2022-04-18 21:43:02.599105: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2022-04-18 21:43:04.340856: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2022-04-18 21:43:04.340964: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2022-04-18 21:43:04.366697: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:328] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2022-04-18 21:43:04.366725: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: g013.anvil.rcac.purdue.edu
2022-04-18 21:43:04.366731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: g013.anvil.rcac.purdue.edu
2022-04-18 21:43:04.366788: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:200] libcuda reported version is: 470.57.2
2022-04-18 21:43:04.366804: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:204] kernel reported version is: 470.57.2
2022-04-18 21:43:04.366810: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:310] kernel version seems to match DSO: 470.57.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x-lyuliyao/ML2/test2.py", line 4, in <module>
    tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(devices=gpus[0], device_type='GPU')
IndexError: list index out of range
2022-04-18 21:43:04.368168: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:328] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2022-04-18 21:43:04.368191: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: g013.anvil.rcac.purdue.edu
2022-04-18 21:43:04.368198: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: g013.anvil.rcac.purdue.edu
2022-04-18 21:43:04.368283: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:200] libcuda reported version is: 470.57.2
2022-04-18 21:43:04.368302: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:204] kernel reported version is: 470.57.2
2022-04-18 21:43:04.368308: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:310] kernel version seems to match DSO: 470.57.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x-lyuliyao/ML2/test2.py", line 4, in <module>
    tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(devices=gpus[0], device_type='GPU')
IndexError: list index out of range```
````

Here is my relevant package version

mpi                       1.0                       mpich
mpi4py                    3.1.1            py39h0a00275_0    https://conda.deepmodeling.org
mpich                     3.3.2                hc856adb_0
tensorflow-base           2.5.0           gpu_py39h7c1560b_0    https://conda.deepmodeling.org
tensorflow-estimator      2.5.0              pyh7b7c402_0
cudatoolkit               11.3.1               h2bc3f7f_2
cudnn                     8.2.1                cuda11.3_0

Comment: Are you sure that you actually have a GPU on your remote node?

Comment: I think yes. Otherwise, I cannot get the right result if I run without using MPI

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm facing the same problem here...